# How to convert 15 Sep 2018 12:00 character to Datetime?

Tags: sas

I am currently trying to convert data that is in:

> 15 Sep 2018 12:00:00

Character to Datetime.

I have managed to successfully convert Character

> 15/08/2018 12:00

to Datetime but not

> 15 Sep 2018 12:00

The data was originally in Excel. When I load 15/08/2018 12:00 in, I will get numbers such as (Numbers May differ)

```
42541.843148148





 > Here is my code(when Character is 15/08/2018 12:00(WORKING)
    > 
    > data have;  
    > input exl_dt;  
    > format date date9.;  
    > format time timeampm.;
    > format dt datetime21.;  
    > date=int(exl_dt)-21916; 
    > time=(exl_dt-int(exl_dt))*60*60*24;  
    > dt=date*24*60*60+time; cards;
    > 42541.843148148 ;
```

However, I am reading another excel now but my character date is now:

> 15 Sep 2018 12:00

The same code above will not be able to convert the value to datetime and only produce blank value.

Code for you to try:

```
data have ;
  datestring = "15 Sep 2018 12:00" ;
run ;
```

How should i handle this?

Comment: Your code returns 15. Please verify it first.

Comment: @Reeza I've changed the datalines statement. Would you mind helping me further?

Comment: Sounds like your real problem is trying to use Excel to store data.  Excel is not a database so it does not enforce that all values in a column are using a single type.  It also has nasty habits of converting strings into numbers or dates.  In your case it is not recognizing your string as a date so it is storing it as a character value instead.  This is what is causing the valid dates to appear in SAS as character strings with the raw number of days that your first data step is converting.

Answer (score 1):

you can try anydtdtm. informat

```
 data have ;
    datestring = "15 Sep 2018 12:00" ;
  dt =input(datestring, anydtdtm.);
  format dt datetime21.;
 run ;
```